# Customize/show/hide navigation bar in BB10 for Android app

Tags: navigationbar

I have ported an Android app to BB10 and it works smoothly except for 1 0r 2 issues. 
One being an issue with bottom navigation bar that holds "Back", "Hide", "Info" and "Overflow" buttons. It shows up by default when the app is launched and can be hidden using the "Hide" button. To retrieve it back on screen we use a BB10 gesture(Swipe from top bezel downwards) and pin it back.
The above behavior works fine in BB10 Simulator, but not in actual device(Z10), which may be due to OS issues as mentioned in some of the posts. 
To overcome the issue I wanted to know is there anyway to Customize/Show(always)/Hide the navigation bar either through Android source code or any settings in Config. Please suggest a way to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. But based on official answers from the Blackberry forums it appears that they would give users some control only in a 'future' release. Please take a look at this link.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Detecting-navigation-bar-presence/m-p/2466821/highlight/true#M5243

This is the exact quote,

> We are looking at an option to allow users to hide the navigation bar.
>   Hopefully this will be available in a future release.